Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 while uploading bundle on play console
I am getting error while uploading release bundle on play store console. I am using same version of dependency:
Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible 
version! Your current com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library is incompatible with 
targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to 
broadcast receivers. As a reminder, from August 31, 2024, Google Play requires all new app 
releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest library version dependency to avoid app 
crashes.

Referenced checked but not worked
Play console policy issue Update com.google.android.play
How to fix "Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version!"?

"I am using same version of dependency" -- how have you determined this?

I have used com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 in build.gradle

That does not necessarily mean that is the version that you are getting. Use the Gradle dependency report to see what version of that artifact you are getting.
